# Can I shrink an NTFS partition running Windows 7 from the 'left' / 'start' side?

Tags: windows, partitioning

This is my current partition layout:

[image: Screenshot, part of Windows Disk Management]

This is the current situation on my hard disk. I have a 25 GB NTFS partition with windows 8 developer preview (drive F) and a 660 GB partition with Windows 7 (my main OS). I have no idea why there's 10 GB of unpartitioned space in the end, but that is easy to deal with via Disk Management in the control panel.

There is a lot of free space on drive C, and I want to take take some of that space to drive F. It's easy to shrink the C partition, but this will leave more space at the right hand side where the unallocated space is which means I won't be able to extend drive F. So is it possible to shrink drive C and move it further to the right on the disk?

I don't mind if the OS that is now running on drive F gets destroyed in the process, I can reinstall it.

Comment: you can split/merge adjacent partitions without much risk...if they are not adjacent, it will involve moving data which can be risky..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EaseUS Partition manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) is a free for home use partition manager. It is really easy and very robust piece of software. AND ITS MADE FOR WINDOWS - So that Windows users can easily use it.

[image]

You can also change the partition on the "LEFT" side. It takes a very long time because it has to move all your files and must be done in exclusive mode, this means a reboot and a blue screen, don't Panic, this blue screen is a console application that does all the magic before windows loads up. Just let it run and it will reboot when done. It never failed me :)

**This will fix all the boot sector issues** - Linux won't, you have to mess around on your own with safe modes and recovery tools; Because Linux GParted just does not apply the appropriate fixes to the Windows partitions :(

Comment: I wonder if this tool can resize your main disk ( since you can't unmount it ), or only an external one?

Comment: You can. It reboots the PC and does it in offline mode :) Then boots back when its done. Its the freakiest thing to see...

Comment: @ppumkin This is a very nice tool, and not having to mess around with making bootable disks or USBs makes this tool much easier to use, and earned my upvote. But that's no reason to bash the GParted based answer. AFAICT, it still gets the job done and is thus still a valid answer.

Comment: :) I updated the answer a bit. I just meant that GParted does not apply the necessary fixes to the partition is it get resized or shifted. SOmetimes it works sometimes not. This soft always worked for me, just like you said- without boot discs and stuff.

Comment: EaseUS appears to have recently started bundling adware in the installer for its free product, without any option to opt out, so be careful if you try it out.

Comment: You can OPT OUT by clicking on ReadTerms during installation. Click on it and a Check box will appear. It is a bit sly and happened after EaseUS was bought by another company. Since then this tool does not work that great any more on newer filesystems and OS's

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) (either on the GParted or [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) [live CDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD)) to shrink the partition and move it to the right. You should make a backup of any important data first, and this process will take a very long time. You also will need to use the Windows cd recovery console to run the `FIXBOOT` command to get the partition booting again after it has been moved.

Comment: are you sure this will work with windows 8? cause the actual boot menu that shows up is the windows 8 one.

Comment: @kyriakos: Windows 8 uses NTFS, so yes, it will work. Moving partitions around does not affect the boot loader. Creating and deleting partition may, however.

Comment: @surfasb, moving windows partitions does affect the boot loader since Microsoft foolishly embeds the absolute start sector of the partition in the boot sector of FAT and NTFS partitions, and the boot loader uses that value instead of what the partition table says.  Hence, the need to run FIXBOOT after moving the start of the partition.

Comment: @Psusi: Ah yes. It didn't use to be that way. The good ol days. . .

Comment: @surfasb, it has been that way since DOS 1.0.

Comment: @psusi: I didn't even know the DOS bootloader was even capable of dualboot.  I always thought it just starts looking for sys.com and MSDOS.SYS. But I doubt the absolute start sector piece.  I've moved partitions around and they boot up just fine.  Plus, from what I can gather, all the volume boot code does is look for ntldr (or bootmgr).

Comment: Why use LINUX to do Windows operations. It really annoys me when people suggest to use Linux software to Windows users. You don't see me going on Linux forums and telling *a-patch-me* users to use IIS 8. You get a -1

Comment: @ppumkin, because Windows isn't capable of doing it.  At the end of the day, what difference does it make as long as you get the job done?  You seem to be confusing "use this Linux tool to do x" with "stop using Windows and install Linux instead".

Comment: It is capable of doing it. And you are confusing Operating Systems with applications. Neither Linux nor Windows can do anything but host application like GParted or EaseUS. In this case EaseUS is much better because it solves all the boot sector problems that GParted can't.

Comment: @ppumkin, I meant the standard windows partitioning tool can't do it.  Good to see that there is now at least a free third party tool that can, though that doesn't make gparted any less of a valid answer.

Comment: GParted worked fine for moving and expanding a Windows 10 partition - even in my very particular case: Windows on Mac, with the Windows BOOTMGR on the partition I moved, but the actual Windows files on another (external) drive. Nevertheless, all I had to do to get Windows booting again was to set the moved partition active (bootable) with `diskpart`, which GParted reset during the move.